# Theory of mind (ToM) training?

Tags: theory-of-mind

As they mention in the paper "Training for generalization in Theory of Mind: a study with older adults", we still need to study more about the ways we can improve our theory of mind ability even as adults.

Any suggestions? (Please include references)

Here are some I found with references:

1. *Reading fiction*:
   the data indicate that reading fiction may be an avenue for improving ToM ability
   "Using Fiction to Assess Mental State Understanding: A New Task for Assessing Theory of Mind in Adults"
2. Possibly [bilingualism](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20685/is-theory-of-mind-formation-accelerated-by-bilingualism) in "Early bilingualism enhances mechanisms of false-belief reasoning".
3. Behavioural synchrony eg. musical orchestra and dancing examples in "Enhancing “theory of mind” through behavioral synchrony"